# Decimal to Fraction Calculator Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make Decimal to Fraction Calculator like (https://www.decimal-to-fraction.com/). But I am facing some issues.
I think it's a jquery issue.

Console error shows ($ is not a function)

I have tried this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var params = GetURLParams();
  if (Object.keys(params).length > 0 && params.x != "") {
    document.getElementById("x").value = params.x;
  }
});

function GetURLParams() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
    params = {},
    match;
  while (match = regex.exec(url)) {
    params[match[1]] = match[2];
  }
  return params;
}
var gcd2 = function(a, b, f) {
  if (f) {
    if (b <= 1)
      return a;
  } else {
    if (!b)
      return a;
  }
  return gcd2(b, a % b, f);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="x" name="x" class="intext form-control" tabindex="1">
<button type="button" title="Convert" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" tabindex="2" onclick="convert()"> Convert</button>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="y" tabindex="5" readonly>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="n" tabindex="6" readonly>
<canvas id="frac"></canvas>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="d" tabindex="7" readonly>
<textarea rows="7" id="area" tabindex="8" class="form-control outtext" readonly></textarea>
```

I got error in console. It says $ is not a function. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Make sure you've added jQuery script in head tag

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library somewhere in your HTML code?

Comment: My question is slightly different - *what* is `$`? If it says it's not a function, then it's *defined*. If jQuery wasn't loaded and that's the only problem you have, then it would say `$ is not defined`

Comment: Either you haven't added jquery to your project, if not here is the link to the jquery CDN ( https://code.jquery.com/ ). Or you have added jquery library before your script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Please include this line during the HTML Render

```js
function GetURLParams() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
        params = {},
        match;
    while (match = regex.exec(url)) {
        params[match[1]] = match[2];
    }
    return params;
}
var gcd2 = function(a, b, f) {
    if( f )
    {
        if ( b<=1 )
            return a;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( !b )
            return a;
    }
    return gcd2(b, a % b, f);
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
     var params = GetURLParams();
    if (Object.keys(params).length > 0 && params.x != "") {
        document.getElementById("x").value = params.x;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="x" name="x" class="intext form-control" tabindex="1">
<button type="button" title="Convert" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" tabindex="2" onclick="convert()"> Convert</button>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="y" tabindex="5" readonly>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="n" tabindex="6" readonly>
<canvas id="frac"></canvas>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="d" tabindex="7" readonly>
<textarea rows="7" id="area" tabindex="8" class="form-control outtext" readonly></textarea>
```

Once you feel its fixed download the JQuery Package and save in your package